# ADSL to Ethernet Cable connection?

Tags: internet, ethernet, adsl, broadband

In summary, my question is whether I can get an internet connection on my laptop by using a cable to connect it to a micro-filter on a phoneline extension. I also have a subsidiary question about which type of cable to use.

I’ve set out some more details below:

I have a wifi router in a bedroom on the first floor of our house. This is plugged into our broadband cable from our ISP. I think, a fairly standard set-up? My son wants to set-up his laptop in a room in our loft, but the problem is that the wifi signal in that room is rather poor. Now the loft room has a phone extension to which I have attached a micro-filter : I’ve plugged a phone into the filter and it works fine, so I know the extension is ok.

So my question is whether I should be able to establish an internet connection by running a lead from the adsl on the micro-filter through to the Ethernet or USB port on the laptop (I know I will probably have to buy some sort of adapter). Or does the fact that I am skipping out the wifi router mean this is impossible? About ten years ago I used to be able to cable link an old desktop to the same phone extension, but I don’t know if there was something different about the  set-up on that computer which made it practical.

My son has a USB port on his laptop and I also have a USB-Etgernet adapter which leads into my follow-up question : have googled adsl-usb and adsl-ethernet cables but I can't find anything of that nature. Am I using the wrong search term, or have I misunderstood what I need

I do know there are two other options for this problem, but I only want to explore them after testing the above question:

1)    I could run a cable from the wifi route into the loft, but that would be quite a big job;

2)    Put in a wifi booster in the loft – more expensive.

Thanks in advance for your help

Chris

Comment: You first mention you have a "cable connection" which is different from ADSL which would be provided through the phone line instead of your cable connection (COAX).  It appears you should simply upgrade your WiFi network.  There are kits that can support a 3,000+ ft living space that works seamlessly.

Comment: Your ISP is unlikely to allow you to set up a second modem/router on a single line [unless you pay them double]. You need to look to stretching the ethernet or WiFi itself.

Comment: Depends how your lines are wired up. Having a dial done doesn't mean you'll get internet access with that port too. To try it, can you can attach the filter and plug into the filter to see if you get internet. If that doesn't work, you can make an ethernet run to the loft, or extend your wifi network with mesh wi-fi routers.

Comment: I think you have some hardware confused.  ADSL setups often had filters to prevent people from hearing digital noise that an ADSL signal would put on the wire while they were using the phone as a phone. .  It wasn't part of the data connection.  For that you'd need an ADSL modem, and more importantly an upstream ISP providing you with ADSL service to your copper wires.  They usually want money for that.